# Recursive function that prints digits of a number in english

Tags: python, recursion

I am working on a program that uses a recursive function to print the digits of a number in English (i.e. 456 would display "Four Five Six".) I noticed someone else recently asked this question but I was unable to get any help from it. The program also requires that multiple numbers be entered from a user and each one should have the corresponding English digits displayed.  I tried doing this in a list but am unsure if that is correct.

Right now I am beyond confused. I have been working on this for hours now and do not have much to show for it. I'm not looking for anyone to write this program for me, just offer some assistance. In theory I know what needs to be done but I'm having a very difficult time translating that into code.

```
def main():
    List = createList()
    print(createList())

def listValue(prompt):
    try:
        number = eval(input(prompt))
        if type(number) == type(0) or type(number) == type(0.0):
            return number
        else:
            print("\nYou did not enter a number. Try again.")
    except NameError:
        print("\nYou did not enter a number. Try again.")
    except SyntaxError:
        print("\nYou did not enter a number. Try again.")
    except:
        print("\nAn exception occured. Try again.")
    if number != "":
        return number
   else:
        return None

def createList():
    #Create a blank list
    newList = []
    item = listValue("Enter a list of numbers (<Enter> to quit): ")
    while item != None:
        #Add user input to the end of the created list
        newList.append(item)
        item = listValue("Enter a list of numbers (<Enter> to quit): ")
    return newList


def displayEnglishDigits(number): 
    numEnglish = {0: "Zero", 1: "One", 2: "Two", 3: "Three", 4: "Four",
                  5: "Five", 6: "Six", 7: "Seven", 8: "Eight", 9: "Nine"}
    digit = Number % 10


main()
```

here is the updated version of my code... any thoughts?

```
    def getNumbers():
        n = []
        xStr = input("Enter first digit of number (negative to quit) >> ")
        integer = int(xStr)
        while  integer >= 0:
            while xStr != "":
                x = eval(xStr)
                n.append(x)
                xStr = input("Enter next digit of number (negative to quit) >> ")
        return n

    def displayEnglishDigits(number):
        numEnglish = {0: "Zero", 1: "One", 2: "Two", 3: "Three", 4: "Four",
                      5: "Five", 6: "Six", 7: "Seven", 8: "Eight", 9: "Nine"}
        number = getNumbers()
        if len(number) == 0:
             return None
        if len(number) == 1:
            return number[0]
       else:
            value = displayEnglishDigits(number[1:])
       return value

    def display(values):
        print(displayEnglishDigits(number))

    def main():
        numb = getNumbers()
        nums = displayEnglishDigits(numb)
        display(nums)

    main()
```

Comment: I assume this is python? Please add the appropriate language tag if python is not it.

Comment: yes it is python, my apologies.

Comment: Ok, now what is happening that shouldn't be happening, or what is not happening that should be happening? You don't say much other than "it doesn't work".

Comment: Well, I haven't even gotten into the bulk of the displayEnglishDigits function, which obviously needs to convert the number into the corresponding english word.  I'm not sure how to call the value from the key. Meaning say the number is 456. I would take the base 10 (456 % 10) and get 6. How do you get it to recognize "six" if that makes sense?

Comment: Also, in order for the user to be able to input multiple numbers, I figured you would need to make a list; however, I'm getting an error message in my listValue function

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "H:\CSC 171\Assignment_10 Test.py", line 34, in <module>
        main()
      File "H:\CSC 171\Assignment_10 Test.py", line 2, in main
        List = createList()
      File "H:\CSC 171\Assignment_10 Test.py", line 31, in createList
        item = listValue("Enter a list of numbers (<Enter> to quit): ")
      File "H:\CSC 171\Assignment_10 Test.py", line 18, in listValue
        if number != "":
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'number' referenced before assignment

Comment: Well note that in `displayEnglishDigits` that the parameter is called `number` but you do `Number % 10`. Also, in `listValue`, you do `print('try again')` but don't have the user try again - execution falls out of the try/catch and to the `if number != ""`, and `number` isn't assigned.

Comment: Regarding how to get each digit, you can use the `list(str(n))` function to turn a number `n` into a list of characters, then process each character by itself.

Comment: Please use the edit feature to add relevant information to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Let's focus on the recursive function, since that's the title.

You've got a good start with the `numEnglish` dictionary.

To finish it off, why not try: turn the number into a string (a list of characters), and write a recursive function that processes the list.

```
numEnglish = {0: "Zero", 1: "One", 2: "Two", 3: "Three", 4: "Four",
              5: "Five", 6: "Six", 7: "Seven", 8: "Eight", 9: "Nine"}

def recursiveDisplay(stringOfNumber):
    if len(stringOfNumber) == 0:            # base case: empty string
      return
    first = int(stringOfNumber[0])          # otherwise, grab the first element
    english = numEnglish[first]             # look it up in the dictionary
    print english                           # print it
    recursiveDisplay(stringOfNumber[1:])    # and recurse on the rest of the list
```

The recursive function has two cases:

- 1) the string is empty:  done processing.  This is the **base case**.
- 2) the string is not empty:  process the first element, and issue a recursive call with everything *but* the first element.  This is the **inductive/recursive** case.

Note that the dictionary `numEnglish` is now defined *outside* of the recursive function.

---

When you call `recursiveDisplay`, make sure to pass it a string!

```
recursiveDisplay(str(myNumber))
```

---

*Disclaimer: using recursion for list processing is not standard python!*

Comment: And using recursion for list processing is a pretty silly thing to do unless it's a requirement for an assignment or something.

Comment: @SethCarnegie -- surprised it hasn't been retagged 'homework' yet.  Thought about it, but didn't make the call.

Comment: I see that in the error he got, the path to the file includes "Assignment 10" so I will retag as hw.

Comment: like I said, I'm not asking for someone to do this for me, I just needed some help.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion for the recursiveDisplay function but i'm a little confused as to how it works.  Try to bare with me, I am very new to python and in particular recursion. I would like to understand it more.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I feel like I'm jumping around a lot because I am still getting errors when I try to obtain the numbers from the user, making it impossible to test. I was trying to create a sentinel loop for obtaining the numbers as I'm sure you should see in my code in the listValue function with <Enter> being the sentinel.  I can't figure out what I have done wrong there and thus, am having a difficult time moving on to the recursion function.

Comment: In my case List would take the place of stringOfNumbers right? I'm just trying to understand how Seth created his recursion function.

Comment: @user1086392 -- I'd suggest writing and testing the display function totally separately from the input bits.  For example, write the display function, then just start using it from the interpreter -- see if it gives you the right results.  Test it for abnormal cases and see what happens.  Whenever you write the input code, even if it's a long time from now, you'll easily be able to plug in your high-quality, throughly tested output routine!

Comment: I have been doing that actually. I've been playing around with the main, listValue and createList functions seperately and the problem is that I can't get my sentinel to work for some reason. ughhh frustrating.

Comment: @user1086392 -- you may want to try asking about that in a separate question, or searching through previously asked questions for help.

Comment: I'm still not seeing how recursiveDisplay would call the dictionary numEnglish

Comment: @BrettWorthington -- I've added that to the example code.  Basically, you want to define `numEnglish` outside the function so that you don't have to create a new copy with every recursive invocation.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is possible you need this for the learning purposes, but anyways:

**Do not do it recursively.**

There are simpler ways to do it and you will not be limited by the max recursion limit set for Python. Just use the following solution:

```
>>> def print_number(some_number):
    for cipher in str(some_number):
        print ['Zero', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four',
               'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine'][int(cipher)],
    print


>>> print_number(126321)
One Two Six Three Two One
```

It works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
numEnglish  = { 0:'zero ', 1:'one ', 2:'two ', 3:'three ', 4:'four ',
                5:'five ', 6:'six', 7:'seven ', 8:'eight ', 9:'nine ' }

def displayEnglishDigits(number):
    if number == 0:
        return ""
    digit = numEnglish[number % 10]
    return displayEnglishDigits(number / 10) + digit
```

Two things to take into account: first, you have to define the `num_names` dictionary as shown above. Second, there's one special case to be aware of - if the number is just 0, print "zero". Otherwise, call `displayEnglishDigits`. Also notice that de procedure returns a string with the digits, you can print it afterwardws.

Comment: didn't I define that in numEnglish? Are you suggesting moving it out of the recursion function like matt and seth? Sorry just trying to understand what you're saying. I'm also not understanding the whole zero thing either.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you call the dictionary, my suggestion is that you should define it outside the function. My other comment: given that I'm treating the number as an int and not as a string, the base case of my recursion is when the number becomes zero. That's ok for every number bigger than zero, because eventually, if you keep dividing it by ten, it´ll become zero. But if the number that was entered was precisely zero, the function will exit without printing anything - that's why zero must be treated as a special case before calling my function.

Comment: Oh okay I see that, thank you for clarifying. I'm still learning so I appreciate the extra help.  So if my program is obtaining multiple numbers from the user, how does that fit into this. You'd have to index each number in the list right?

Answer (score 0):

Please find my piece of code for the same, please lemme if its possible reduce further.

```
from __future__ import print_function

helper={}
helper = {1:"one",
        2:"two",
3:"three",
4:"four",
5:"five",
6:"six",
7:"seven",
8:"eight",
9:"nine",
0:""}

face = {}
face = { 0:"zero",
1:
        {0:"",
        1:
                {0:"ten",
                1:"eleven",
                2:"twelve",
                3:"thirteen",
                4:"fourteen",
                5:"fifteen",
                6:"sixteen",
                7:"seventeen",
                8:"eighteen",
                9:"ninteen"
        },
        2:"twenty",
        3:"thirty",
        4:"fourty",
        5:"fifty",
        6:"sixty",
        7:"seventy",
        8:"eighty",
        9:"ninety"},
2:"hundred",
3:"thousand"}

result = ""
teen = ""

def rec_ntw(number, face_value=0):
        global result
        global teen
        if number <= 0:
                if face_value == 0:
                        result = "Zero"
                print (result)
                #return result
        else:
                if face_value == 0:
                        result = (helper[int(number % 10)])
                        teen = number % 10
                elif face_value == 1:
                        if number % 10 == 1:
                                result = (face[1][1][int(teen)]) + " "
                        else:
                                result = (face[int(face_value)][int(number % 10)]) + " " + result
                                teen = 0
                elif face_value == 2:
                        if number % 10 != 0:
                                result = (helper[int(number % 10)] + " " + str(face[int(face_value)]) + " ") + result
                else:
                        result = (helper[int(number % 10)] + " " + str(face[int(face_value)]) + " ") + result
                face_value += 1
                rec_ntw(number // 10, face_value)



while True:
        try:
                user_input = input("Please enter the number: ")
                rec_ntw(user_input)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break
```